# What is the syntax for MongoDB query for boolean values?

Tags: mongodb

The values for the key `is_agent` is TRUE or blank.

I have the following query:

```
db.users.find( { $not: {is_agent:TRUE} }, {email:1} )
```

I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: TRUE is not defined
```

When I used `"TRUE"` I got the following error:

```
"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $not",
"code" : 17287
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> `$eq` Matches values that are **equal** to a specified value.
>
> `$ne` Matches all values that are **not equal** to a specified value.

[Documentation on mongodb operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nav-query/)

Example:

```
db.users.find({is_agent: {$ne: true}})
```

or

```
db.users.find({is_agent: {$eq: true}})
```